# Cannot add new user to database - Spring boot: 400 BadRequest

Tags: java, spring

I have a problem with the application. I have created 2 services, one of which (db-connector) connects to the database and allows some actions and the second (webApp) used by the browser connects to the first.

When I'm trying to create user using Postman it works. So bug must be in method below

```
@PostMapping("/createUser")
public String createUser(@ModelAttribute("createQuery") CreateQuery createQuery) {
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON);

    User user = new User();
    user.setLogin(createQuery.getLogin());
    user.setPassword(createQuery.getPassword());
    user.setFirstName(createQuery.getFirstName());
    user.setLastName(createQuery.getLastName());

    HttpEntity<User> request = new HttpEntity<>(user, headers);
    restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/createUser", request, User.class);

    return "createUser";
}
```

It returns:

```
Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 : [{"timestamp":"2020-09-10T14:57:56.859+00:00","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"","path":"/createUser"}]] with root cause

org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 : [{"timestamp":"2020-09-10T14:57:56.859+00:00","status":400,"error":"Bad Request","message":"","path":"/createUser"}]
```

I've tried do it in such a way:

```
HttpEntity<User> request = new HttpEntity<>(new User(), headers);
        restTemplate.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/createUser?userLogin=" + createQuery.getLogin()
                + "&password=" + createQuery.getPassword() + "&firstName=" + createQuery.getFirstName()
                + "&lastName=" + createQuery.getLastName(), request, User.class);
```

Tried to changed postForEntity to postForObject, but still doesn't work. I can't figure out what is wrong.

Cheers :)

Comment: Are you using `restTemplate` for accessing endpoints in the same server? Why would you do that? You can simply call the service method

Comment: you created a post request but passing parameters like a get?

Comment: One has 8080 port and second has 8081 if that what you mean

Comment: Please show the postman request that is working. That way we can compare it to the request that is not working.

Comment: @KalpeshSoni I don't get your point

Comment: createUser?userLogin=xx thats a get parameter not post

Comment: It works in this way when I call it in a browser

Comment: If you want it to be sent as the body you should use @RequestBody in your controller code

Answer (score 0):

[

```
2020-09-10 17:39:34.284 DEBUG 2116 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing SQL update and returning generated keys
2020-09-10 17:39:34.285 DEBUG 2116 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [INSERT INTO EXAMPLE_SCHEMA.USERS(login, password, first_name, last_name) values(?, ?, ?, ?)]
2020-09-10 17:39:50.421 DEBUG 2116 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2020-09-10 17:39:50.421 DEBUG 2116 --- [nio-8080-exec-2] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE_SCHEMA.USERS WHERE login LIKE ?]
2020-09-10 17:39:52.983 DEBUG 2116 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL query
2020-09-10 17:39:52.983 DEBUG 2116 --- [nio-8080-exec-3] o.s.jdbc.core.JdbcTemplate               : Executing prepared SQL statement [SELECT * FROM EXAMPLE_SCHEMA.USERS WHERE login LIKE ?]
```

]

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rWQ2H.png)

It is response from first service that aim is to connect the database